# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jaxen/jdom/JDOMXPath

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror, jdom

I've got a problem using jDOM 1.0 with weblogic6. Just using the method `XPath.newInstance(String)`, we encounter the following error message:

```
Caused by:
  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jaxen/jdom/JDOMXPath
    at org.jdom.xpath.JaxenXPath.setXPath(JaxenXPath.java:281)
    at org.jdom.xpath.JaxenXPath.<init>(JaxenXPath.java:99)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
```

The class Parent is present in the jdom jar which is located in the lib directory of our web application. (Such as the jaxen beta 9 jar). I added `Jdom.jar and Jaxen beta 9 jar in classpath.

But don't really understand which solution is to be applied.

There is obviously a conflict with jaxen jar but what should we do exactly?

Comment: I take it you've checked whether `org.jaxen.jdom.JDOMXPath` is on your classpath? It's not necessarily enough for the jar to be in your lib folder. If you're using Eclipse, you can right-click your project and to Properties to check your build path. If the jar is in a different project than where you're using it, make sure the jar is also exported.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java